# Is it possible to mysqldump with partition() in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have to dump large amount of tables with different partition keys.

So if I can dump tables using `partition()` it would make my job slightly easier.

---

I'm currently doing like this :

```
mysqldump $DB_NAME $TB_NAME --where="${part_expr} >= '${part_cnd_from}' and ${part_expr} < '${part_cnd_to}'" > ${backup_path}
```

---

And I'm wondering if I can do something like this

```
mysqldump $DB_NAME "$TB_NAME partition(${partition_name})" > ${backup_path}
```